# Two VMs on my Ubuntu server cannot be pinged

Tags: networking, server, virtualization

I created two RedHat VMs on an Ubuntu server.  I changed the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file to have a unique MAC address b/c the VMs were created from an image.  I changed the IP address.  I rebooted the server.  The VMs can ping each other.  I cannot ping the VMs from the Ubuntu server.

When I try, I get

```
ping x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data
```

Nothing happens after that.  When I cancel the ping, I see 100% packet loss.

When I am on a VM and try to ping the parent server, I get

```
Destination Host Unreachable
```

So I cannot even ping the host server from the guest VMs.

**Update:**

Some VMs have working IP addresses.  The new VMs that I created don't have working IP addresses.  On the physical server, I did an arp -an command.   The working VMs have IP addresses with MAC addresses.  The VMs that don't work have IP addresses with no MAC addresses. How do I make a VM's IP address have a MAC address?

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose proper networking mode for your VMs' network interface. Either choose bridged mode which will allow you to ping host and go to the internet, or host-only network (private network) which won't let you browse the internet but will allow you to reach the host.
Do not choose NAT (which I suspect is your current mode).

Comment: I believe NAT is the default.  I always use Bridged unless I have a VM that explicitly offers service to the host and not anything else.

Comment: How do I know what mode I am using? virsh edit NameOfVm shows me an XML document without the word "nat."  I can use the GUI of Virtual Machine Manager too.